# blank screen after booting

Tags: boot, 16.04, grub2, nvidia, graphics

After a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04 from .iso, I installed Nvidia drivers as seen [here](https://medium.com/@vivek.yadav/deep-learning-setup-for-ubuntu-16-04-tensorflow-1-2-keras-opencv3-python3-cuda8-and-cudnn5-1-324438dd46f0) to use with a GTX 1070.

When I reset my system I lost monitor support.  I see the Ubuntu splash screen and then the screen goes blank before I get to the login page.  **How can I get monitor support back?**

Additional information:

- adding `nomodeset` seems to fix the problem, at least for Ubuntu live (usb).  However, I am unable to add this flag to the installed version of Ubuntu because I can't access the bootloader/BIOS screen (holding `delete` or `shift` when booting).
- I tried to add `nomodeset` via mounting the SSD from Ubuntu Live, but it complains that ~ "Linux reports a block size of 512 whereas the device reports 2048".  If I could get the fs mounted, I think I could fix my problem.
- I am unable to get to the installed Ubuntu BIOS/boot loader; I have tried holding `shift` and `delete` on startup.
- Even if I get into BIOS, most options are offscreen (because the resolution is not native, I think).  This means I would also need to restore the native resolution somehow before changing settings in the BIOS GUI.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was likely due to a firmware issue reported with the Dell u2414h monitor.  Using an HDMI vs displayport cable seemed to instantly return monitor support.

Of greater utility, resetting the BIOS by removing the CMOS battery on the motherboard was helpful in returning the BIOS to its original configuration without monitor support.